# Nginx not compressing response of HTTP POST?

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have Nginx setup as a reverse proxy between the world and my app, and it's successfully gzipping the proxied responses of GET requests with this general config:

```
gzip on;
gzip_min_length 0;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types application/json text/plain;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
proxy_http_version 1.1;
```

The browser sends the POST with seemingly the right headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

However in the response header there's no `Content-Encoding` even thought it has `Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Can Nginx gzip the HTTP POST Response?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I did not, in the end I decided to compress the response upstream of Nginx where it's generated.  I didn't pursue trying to chase down if this is considered a bug in Nginx or not.

Comment: I've been running into this error too. Maybe it's a bug in nginx, I'm going to update nginx and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Updating nginx to 1.17 from 1.14 did not fix this.